nginx 404 on the start page of the application
I have a backend running on port 8000 and a frontend running on port 3000. After setting up nginx, when I go to https://example.com returns 404.
Here are the settings
for /etc/nginx/sites-available/example.com
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name example.com www.example.com;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name example.com www.example.com;

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.example.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.example.com/privkey.pem;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
    }

    location /api {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8000;
        proxy_set_header    Host              $host;
    }
}

Here are the /etc/nginx/sites-available/default
server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server;
        root /var/www/html;
        index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

        server_name _;

        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }
}

/api working, but start page - 404
